# C++ Cannot open include file: "vector": No such file or directory

Tags: visual-c++, vector, compiler-errors

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

I am having this weird vector error in C++ Visual Studio 2015. I have tried many times to add it to the directories in properties in `Additional Include`. That does not seem to fix the error.

Comment: My guess is, you've actually deleted <vector> file, perhaps accidentally. Run Visual Studio installer again, choose Repair.

Comment: Don't post images of text! All of these things can be (and should have been) copied and pasted directly into your question.